# Random sampling row in pandas using probability column

Tags: python, pandas, random

I am using python with pandas to draw random samples from a dataframe.
My dataframe looks like this:

Column one contains time, second one is an average rate, third is the 1-sigma and the fourth column is the probability associated with the event described by the row.

[image]

I know that I can use this code to draw weighted samples:

```
random=df.sample(n=100000, replace=True, weights='P>0', axis=0)
```

But I am not sure that a probability is the correct "weight" to use here. 
In short, I need that a value with low P>0 is sampled less frequently than a value with P>0.

Is anyone willing to share opinions / different options on this?

Thank you!

Comment: That seems correct to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the 'P>0' column as the weights will indeed result in those values with higher values of P being sampled more than those with lower values. But note that a row's value of P doesn't correspond to the probability of being sampled because the Ps don't sum up to one. First pandas will normalize the column P so that it does add up to one and then sample according to those normalized probabilities.

Here's a quick test I did which demonstrates this. First I generate a dataframe containing a column P with the weights (unnormalized), then I sample from the dataframe with column P giving the weights between 0 and 1 with equal numbers of rows of each weight. You can see in the output that the rows with higher weights constitute a greater proportion of the sampled result than the lower weights.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ps = np.tile(np.arange(0,1,0.1),1000)
df = pd.DataFrame({"id":range(0,10000),"P":ps})

print(df.sample(1000,weights="P")["P"].value_counts(normalize=True))
>>>
0.9    0.207
0.8    0.188
0.7    0.152
0.6    0.119
0.5    0.109
0.4    0.084
0.3    0.065
0.2    0.052
0.1    0.024
Name: P, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I suspected this was how it was working, but wasn't sure.